# Rshiny: display list of dataframes after running a function using input select from list

Tags: r, shiny

I wrote a function to analyse xml files. number of files can range from 1 to ca. 80. The function uses the name of a given file. The list of files ((class(list) = typeof(list)= character)) in a given folder is created using

```
    files <- list.files(pattern = "\\.xml$")
```

which gives

```
"file1.xml"  "file2.xml"  "fileN.xml"
```

The function looks like

```
myfunction < function (x){
 ....
 result_list <- list(result1, result2, result3)
 return(result_list)
}
```

and can be called with

```
myresults <- myfunction(files[[1]])
```

or

```
myresults <-  myfunction("file2.xml")
```

I need a simple shiny app that has a SelectInput box, which A) show the list of files in the folder, and B) from which the user selects one of the files (e.g.  "file1.xml"). This selected file name needs to be passed on to the output which runs the function and shows the three resulting dataframes like

```
selectInput          result 1
 file1.xml             [dataframe result 1]
 file2.xml
 fileN.xml           result 2
                        [dataframe result 2]

                     result 3
                        [dataframe result 2]
```

I managed so far:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel('XML Workbook'),
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("variable", "XML Files: ",
              list( "files" ), selected = files[[1]])
    ),
  mainPanel(
    h4("results Part 1"),
    tableOutput("result1"),
    br(),
    h4("results Part 2"),
  tableOutput("result2"),
  br(),
  h4("results Part 3"),
  tableOutput("result3")
  )
 )
 )

shinyServer(function(input,output){
output$result1<- renderTable({
myresults [[1]]
 })

 output$result2<- renderTable({
myresults [[2]]
 })

 output$result3<- renderTable({
myresults [[3]]
```

})
})

What I don't manage is the interactivity: A) The selectInput box to show the list of files, B) to run the function in the output using the selected file from the selectInput box.

Any help is extremely appreciated!!

Comment: What you need is to use `renderUI` to dynamically render your selectInput with list of files (i.e. have a function that returns the list of files on the server end, and call renderUI on the server end to populate the selectInput). Once the ui end returns a selection, on the backend use `observeEvent` to monitor this selection event, get the file path (input$variable$datapath), and run your script.

Comment: Great, thanks! Nearly there  :)